# Chrome dev-tools, who is setting the height/width?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I found that I am helpless - when I need to find who is responsible for setting elements property values. It usually takes a while to pin point the problem.

Can anybody share the best strategy if you come to the page - see that computed height is "500px", but no body set it explicitly - yes, I eventually find the reason but I would like to be a bit more methodical.

Thank you

Comment: i have always wondered why it's so hard to find the last applied... usually i have to scroll up and down like many times then after trial and error i just do it. usually i just add new style over previous instead of bothering to deal with interconnected complex code written by someone else. It's going to get harder once css is more javascript like.

Comment: Me too :-), Muhammad.

Comment: The rendering engine is doing this, so I don't think there's a quick way.  It's probably possible to detect this programmatically but I'm not aware of a good tool.  I'm not sure there's a better way then tracing up levels.  I find dev tools in chrome pretty useful for tracing up, because you can hover and see how big each element is, and when the size jumps that's usually the culprit (or a good place to start).

Comment: The trouble is there's no exact science for doing this native in css, especially if percentages have been used and javascript has altered any of the DOM. It is one of the reasons people moved to using preprocessor languages (sass / less) because they allow the use of [sourcemaps](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/css-preprocessors)

Comment: Great advice. Will try this way. Thank you, Brian

Comment: I use stylus, but how to use sourcemaps for this task?

Answer (score 9):

For **Google Chrome** browser

- right click on element and select `Inspect element`
- expand `Computed` tab and look for offending style
- find property that you need and click small triangle to the left of style definition. On click it should expand list of selectors that affects this style for this element

---

Read more

- [How to Determine Which CSS is Styling an Element](https://atendesigngroup.com/blog/how-determine-which-css-styling-element) (Chrome, Safari, FF)

[image]